# Assign Username To Wallet Address

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

I have Created Dapp in Which People can Sign in With Their Metamask , How Can I Add Option To Assign a Nickname or Username to Their Wallet Address When They Sign in and Show the Username in the Dapp?

Comment: Hello PankajBhadane! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! What library are you using for the login?

Comment: I was Using Simple React.Js

Comment: In react the library web3-react is used frequently for login purposes. The nickname I think it is something specific to your app. For names in Ethereum [ENS](https://ens.domains/) is the more common. Sorry, but the question is too vague.